# Is there a non commutative ring with quotient ring is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

We have a result if $R$ is commutative, then so is any quotient ring $R/I$, for any ideal $I$. If we take the contrapositive, we see that if $R/I$ is non commutative, then $R$ is non commutative.
Is there any noncommutative ring that has a commutative quotient ring?
If so, give an example.

Comment: You can consider a direct sum of a commutative and a non-commutative ring, for example.

Comment: Why not flesh out my hint and post it as an Answer to your own Question?  It's a good practice!

Answer (score 8):

Consider a direct sum of a commutative ring $M$ and a non-commutative ring $N$, say $M \times N$. Then the quotient ring $(M \times N)/(\{0\} \times N)$ is isomorphic to $M$, which is commutative.

Answer (score 4):

let $R$ be a noncommutative ring. Take $I=R$.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is an ideal of itself. $R/R\cong\{0\}$

---

A non trivial example:

$U_n(\Bbb{R})=\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}\}$

$D_n(\Bbb{R})=\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&c\end{pmatrix}:a,c\in\Bbb{R}\}$

$U_n(\Bbb{R})$ is non commutative and $D_n(\Bbb{R})$ is commutative ring.

Define a map:

$\phi:U_n(\Bbb{R})\to D_n(\Bbb{R})$ by $$\phi(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}) =  \begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&c\end{pmatrix}  $$

Claim:

1. $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism from $U_n(\Bbb{R})$onto$ D_n(\Bbb{R})$
2. $\ker(\phi) =\{\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}:b\in\Bbb{R}\}$
3. $U_n(\Bbb{R})/\ker(\phi) \cong D_n(\Bbb{R})$