# Prove(or disprove) If $R/S $ is commutative ring then $R$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Given that $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a ring and $S$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R/S$ is a quotient ring.
Is there any example such that $R/S$ is commutative ring but $R$ is not commutative ring ?

Comment: $R$ is an ideal of itself!

Comment: Exact duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672034/977780).